# Is it possible to change a created iReport file (jrxml) by Java external app

Tags: java, properties, jasper-reports

I want to know is that possible to change properties value of fields in iReport, using Java external application.

For example, firstly I create a report name abc.jrxml. Here is a  part of XML code of abc.jrxml file.

```xml
<reportElement x="117" y="2" width="65" height="20" uuid="2f281676-e098-4213-b1d3-57b845960b2a"/>
```

I want to change that values: x="117" to x="200". height="20" to height="25". I want to try it by java commands. Is that possible or not. If it is possible how can I can make it.

Comment: You can use JasperReports API. There are a lot of samples using of this library

Comment: @AlexK Thank u sir

Comment: @PetterFriberg an interesting link. Thank u sir.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Alex K. pointed out, the best way to change attributes with a Java application is to create the Reports with the Jasper Reports API.

For example in one answer to 
http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/525188/dynamic-width-textfied-parameter the width of an object was changed before the report was generated:

```
JasperDesign design = xmlLoader.loadXML(..jrxmlStream..);
JRElement[] elements = design.getDetail().getElements();
String elementKey = ..key of element to modify..;
int newWidth = ..new element width..;
for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
{
    JRDesignElement element = (JRDesignElement) elements[i];
    if (elementKey.equals(element.getKey())) {
        element.setWidth(newWidth);
    }
}
```

You can use additionally `setHeight`, `setX()` and `setY()` to change the elements properties.

More information is provided here: http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jasperreports-library-reference-materials

Comment: @tobi6 Thank you sir. You solved my problem.

Comment: @MartinWickman Agree with you.