# How to set TextField property in PDF Jasper reports using JAVA

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am trying to set Text Field property : "Stretch with overflow" to true for all the text fields that appear in my pdf report, while exporting. I am using below for the same:

```
JRDesignTextField text = new JRDesignTextField();
text.setStretchWithOVerflow(true);
```

But, I want to know how to use this while exporting so that it is applied to all my reports generated in pdf format.

Or if there is a better way to do the same?

Comment: You can iterate over all element of *JasperDesign* and set the property. Like at this post: [Is it possible to change a created iReport file (jrxml) by Java external app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37155911/876298)